# Chrome is displaying only a white screen but it's clickable (not frozen)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, white-screen

we just began experiencing this problem today.  Chrome opens a white window with the _ and X visible in the top right corner.  No tabs, address bar, etc.

I can position the cursor and click where the Chrome menu is supposed to be, and the menu appears.

If I resize the window, the new areas appear solid black.

I have uninstalled chrome manually, deleting the C:\program files (x86) directory, the appdata directory, and the registry keys.

Then I rebooted and reinstalled Chrome from chrome.google.com and still get the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't experienced this in Chrome, but in Firefox I have had conflicts between my video drivers and Firefox's "Hardware Acceleration" which caused similar behavior.  You might want to try launching Chrome from the command line or run box using the following switch:

```
chrome.exe --disable-gpu
```

This will temporarily disable the hardware acceleration feature in Chrome.  If this works, be sure to turn it off manually on the settings page.  You may also want to try running launching in Incognito mode:

```
chrome.exe --incognito
```

Since this typically disables all add-ons, so you can check if those were the cause of the issue.

Comment: Disabling GPU seems to work.  Why would this need to be done after it's been working up until yesterday?  What should I check?  No events in Event Viewer mention GPU problems or graphics card driver issues.

Comment: @Ryan My guess would be an automatic update to either your video driver or to chrome itself. When it happened to me in FF it was always at random. Checking for a new video driver or rolling back to an older one may fix the issue. For FF I just ended up leaving the hardware acceleration off.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but this solution does not work for me.

I see a solution in https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gfSEhLj7cF0 - rename the executable name of "chrome.exe" to anything else.

Very strange, but works fine.

Comment: Anyone have more details on this one?  I have just experienced it with the latest Chrome build (ChromeStandaloneSetup64 v120.0.6099.217 released 01-11-2024), and the *only* fix that actually works is this wonky rename of the .EXE.  Dyin

Comment: I did find another clue, dig thru registry and pull any instances of 'chrome.exe' out on one of the uninstall/reinstall cycles....

not sure if this is the one, but i'm back in business:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe

Answer (score 0):

My solution (in an Ubuntu-ThinClient Environment not on windows 10) was to use the following parameter:

```
chromium-browser --use-gl=swiftshader
```

Found at https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

`--disable-gpu` was without effect.

Answer (score 0):

2023 update: Google Chrome broke after an automated update. Spent hours trying to search and try various white screen fixes. No tabs couldn't get into settings, etc. I cleaned the registry, uninstalled everything including roaming data and still it wouldn't work.  Finally found this site. turning off HW accelleration just turned it from white to pure black...but changing the name of the executable fixed it.  Who would have guessed that would work?  I renamed chrome.exe to fredchrome.exe  and everything is working again.  I also scanned for viruses, trojans, malware nothing in the pc (Win10 22H2).  Not sure what they did on the update but thanks for pointing to this as a possible fix!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1205169)